# Testing modal dialogs with zombie.js

Tags: coffeescript, pug, zombie.js

I have some input fields inside a modal dialog like so (that's jade):

```
      .modal-body
            .control-group
                label.required(for="event-planner-email")= Email
                .input
                    input#event-planner-email(name="email", type='text')

            .control-group
                label.required(for="event-planner-name")= Name
                .input
                    input#event-planner-name(name="name", type='text')
```

And I would like to be able to fill them out in a test. I tried pressing the link that opens the modal and filling the fields using zombie.js browser object, code in coffee follows:

```
          browser.clickLink 'a#open-planner', () ->
                browser
                    .fill('event-planner-email', someEmail)
                    .fill('event-planner-name', someName)
                    .pressButton 'Create', () ->
                         do done
```

But I get an error saying: "No INPUT matching 'event-planner-email'". If anyone knows how to do this, help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the modal has not come into view yet by the time your call back is firing.  If there is a transition happening to show the modal, you'll have to wait for that transition to complete.

Maybe try adding a `setTimeout` in your call back of the `clickLink`:

```
browser.clickLink 'a#open-planner', ->
    fillForm = ->
        browser
            .fill('event-planner-email', someEmail)
            .fill('event-planner-name', someName)
            .pressButton 'Create', ->
                 do done

    setTimeout fillForm, 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

You need to run your zombie code after the modal loads, so you should use the "shown" event

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  // zombie
})
```

I'm not sure how to represent that in coffee

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, turns out I just didn't use the proper css selector for the input elements, so instead of

```
                .fill('event-planner-email', someEmail)
```

should be

```
                .fill('input#event-planner-email', someEmail)
```

Because in jade snippet above, 'event-planner-email' is the id of the input element. Wanted to delete my question, so that I don't expose my stupidity any further, but apparently it's too late.